# How would I put my list of Dictionary index values in an if statement?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, ios

I have a uitableview which I would like to grayout the text if the cell is in a list of index values stored in a NSdictionary.  As you can see I have my list of indexs to gray out stored in a nsdictionary where I get fuzzy is how to move that list into the if(condition???)

```
NSDictionary *myIndexList = [[inList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"myIndex"];
   NSLog( @"data from INDEX !!!!!!!! %@", myIndexList);

   if (indexPath.row == ???myIndexList????) {

       cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
   }
```

Many Thanks and I hope this novice question finds you well.

Comment: I did have an answer here but deleted it when I realized your question is a little too confusing for me to properly answer. For example, why are you using a dictionary instead of an array which contains the list of indexes you want to gray out?

Comment: I agree with Michael, I gave you a solution if the dictionary contains keys that contain the rows you want grayed out, but if you just want an array of indexes then you should use `NSArray` not `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(NSString *aKey in myIndexList)
{
    if(indexPath.row == [myIndexList valueForKey:aKey])
    {
         cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
}
```

This code will check through all the keys in the dictionary and if the value for a particular key is equal to the row it will change the text color to `lightGrayColor`.

Now if you are just returning `myIndexList` as an `NSArray` instead of an `NSDictionary` you would use this:

```
for(int n=0; n<[myIndexList count]; n++)
{
    if(indexPath.row == [[myIndexList objectAtIndex:n] integerValue])
    {
         cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
}
```